# Magento 2: How to get sub category and their products in collection?

Tags: magento2, collection

I want to get the categories and related products in collection using parent category ID. So that i can show the grid like

sub category 1

```
sub category 1's product 1
sub category 1's product 2
sub category 1's product 3
```

sub category 2

```
sub category 2's product 1
sub category 2's product 2
sub category 2's product 3
```

and so on. I can get the products in foreach but I need to add pagination also.

Comment: I think for that first you'll need to get all the sub categories after that you'll get all the products of the specific categories.

Comment: @AsadKhan I want to print as it is given in the question. And I need to add the pagination if list is big, that's why I am searching for collection

Answer (score 1):

Step by step guide to add pagination in custom collection of Magento 2:
1 Create Collection for Pager:

```
protected $categorycollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(\Magecomp\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categorycollectionFactory) 
    { 
        $this->categorycollectionFactory = $categorycollectionFactory; 
    }
    public function getCategorydata()
    {
        $categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        return $collection;
    }
```

2. Add Collection to Pager and Set Available Limits.

   `protected function _prepareLayout()
       {
           parent::_prepareLayout();
           $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Categories'));
           if ($this->getNews()) {
               $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
               'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
               'magecomp.category.pager'
               )->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15))->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
               $this->getCategorydata()
               );
               $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
               $this->getCategorydata()->load();
           }
           return $this;
       }`
3. Getting the Child Block of the Pager

   `public function getPagerHtml()
   {
       return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
   }`
4. Add the following Code in phtml File to Call the Pager:

   `<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
       <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
   <?php endif ?>`